# Magento 2 ACL is not working on custom controller

Tags: magento2, admin, acl

I have tried to use ACL on custom admin controller but it is not working.

My `etc/acl.xml` file is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Vendor_Module::index_index" sortOrder="10" title="Tool Title"/>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

**Controller location**:

> Vendor/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index.php

I have also added this function in my controller

```
protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Vendor_Module::index_index');
}
```

After this, option appearing in admin role, but after assigning to role, tool is not appearing on that specific role user.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: please check this one - https://alanstorm.com/magento_2_understanding_access_control_list_rules/

Comment: Yes I will, please check the code that I have shared, if I am missing anything please do let me know. Thanks :)

Comment: try with isAllowed('Vendor_Module::index_index') instead of isAllowed('Vendor_Module::vendor_module_index_index')

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing an entry in the `authorization_rule` table. Find your group role ID in the `authorization_role` table and check to see if it has a paired entry with your resource ID (in your case, `Venodr_Module::index_index`) in the `authorization_rule` table. If not, try saving the group role again or manually add entry into the table.